# Software for solving large systems of linear equations over gf(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, software-recommendation

What available solvers are there for linear equation solver over GF(2) (Boolean), capable of dealing with large sparse systems (in the 10k - 100k variables range)?

Comment: My master's supervisor was involved in a paper on that topic, it is written for cryptography though. The paper is "An Improved Algorithm for Iterative Matrix-Vector Multiplications over Finite Fields" by Mangir et al. I think they published a follow-up paper too. I didn't check what is happening in that area for a long time, but it was quite barren without much interest until 2018.